# Can't burn DVD -- incompatible format

Tags: fedora, dvd, burning

I have been trying to burn a few ISOs lately with no success and have certainly used this hardware in the past, so I am not sure what's going on. I am using DVD-R media (tried multiple discs) which appears to be supported by my drive. Here is the error I received in GnomeBaker on Fedora 14 (64):

```
Executing 'builtin_dd if=/home/tja/Downloads/Torrents/bodhi_0.1.6.iso of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
:-[ PERFORM OPC failed with SK=2h/CANNOT WRITE MEDIUM - INCOMPATIBLE FORMAT]: Wrong medium type
/dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 1.0x1352KBps.
:-[ WRITE@LBA=0h failed with SK=2h/CANNOT WRITE MEDIUM - INCOMPATIBLE FORMAT]: Wrong medium type
:-( media is not formatted or unsupported.
:-( write failed: Wrong medium type
```

...and this:

```
$ cdrecord -prcap
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/cdrw
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'Memorex '
Identification : 'DVD+/-DLRWL1 F16'
Revision       : 'BWSB'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.

Drive capabilities, per MMC-3 page 2A:

  Does read CD-R media
  Does write CD-R media
  Does read CD-RW media
  Does write CD-RW media
  Does read DVD-ROM media
  Does read DVD-R media
  Does write DVD-R media
  Does not read DVD-RAM media
  Does not write DVD-RAM media
  Does support test writing

  Does read Mode 2 Form 1 blocks
  Does read Mode 2 Form 2 blocks
  Does read digital audio blocks
  Does restart non-streamed digital audio reads accurately
  Does support Buffer-Underrun-Free recording
  Does read multi-session CDs
  Does read fixed-packet CD media using Method 2
  Does not read CD bar code
  Does read R-W subcode information
  Does not return R-W subcode de-interleaved and error-corrected
  Does read raw P-W subcode data from lead in
  Does return CD media catalog number
  Does return CD ISRC information
  Does support C2 error pointers
  Does not deliver composite A/V data

...
```

more info:

```
$ dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0
INQUIRY:                [Memorex ][DVD+/-DLRWL1 F16][BWSB]
GET [CURRENT] CONFIGURATION:
 Mounted Media:         11h, DVD-R Sequential
 Media ID:              RITEKF1     
 Current Write Speed:   4.0x1385=5540KB/s
 Write Speed #0:        4.0x1385=5540KB/s
 Write Speed #1:        2.0x1385=2770KB/s
 Write Speed #2:        1.0x1385=1385KB/s
GET [CURRENT] PERFORMANCE:
 Write Performance:     4.0x1385=5540KB/s@[0 -> 0]
 Speed Descriptor#0:    00/0 R@3.2x1385=4432KB/s W@4.0x1385=5540KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#1:    00/0 R@3.2x1385=4432KB/s W@2.0x1385=2770KB/s
 Speed Descriptor#2:    00/0 R@3.2x1385=4432KB/s W@1.0x1385=1385KB/s
READ DVD STRUCTURE[#10h]:
 Media Book Type:       00h, DVD-ROM book [revision 0]
 Legacy lead-out at:    2298496*2KB=4707319808
READ DVD STRUCTURE[#0h]:
 Media Book Type:       25h, DVD-R book [revision 5]
 Last border-out at:    2045*2KB=4188160
READ DISC INFORMATION:
 Disc status:           blank
 Number of Sessions:    1
 State of Last Session: empty
 "Next" Track:          1
 Number of Tracks:      1
READ TRACK INFORMATION[#1]:
 Track State:           invisible incremental
 Track Start Address:   0*2KB
 Next Writable Address: 0*2KB
 Free Blocks:           2297888*2KB
 Track Size:            2297888*2KB
READ CAPACITY:          0*2048=0
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what caused this? I just reinstalled Fedora today (for other reasons) and I am still unable to burn a DVD. I am using Memorex DVD-R discs, and have tried different ones. The drive appears to read media just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `dvd+rw-mediainfo` say about the discs? (Under Debian, that utility is in the `dvd+rw-tools` package.)

Comment: Updated...I noticed that the reported transfer speed is slightly different...1385 vs 1382...not sure if thats an issue.

Comment: So I tried a DVD+R and it worked. Ill report back after I do more digging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to find out exactly what types of disks your burner will support.

That error message indicates it doesn't support DVD-R (as backed up by your comment that it did work with a DVD+R disk)

As Gilles commented, you should be able to use `dvd+rw-mediainfo` but failing that, you could look at the physical writer itself.

Comment: +1 and if my memory serves me well, there was a bug in 'cdrecord' back at the beginning of '11. I remember I switched for a while to crdao (or something similar) to be able to write DVD-R disks.

Comment: This driver later stopped functioning altogether, but thanks for the answer.