# Linux Mint: Incompatible Media Format for Burning Images on DVD DL

Tags: linux-mint, dvd, burning

I've tried using Brasero and K3B but nothing seems to work. My discs are Memorex DVD+R DL and my burner says RW DVD+R DL on it. This is not identical to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8659/cant-burn-dvd-incompatible-format) because the formats should be compatible unless my burner is lying to me. Here is my log:

```
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_ILGRLY.bin toc = none
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_WPFRLY.bin toc = none
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_Q5RRLY.bin toc = none
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Starting checksuming file /[....]/Xeno.iso (size = 8511160320)
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Setting new checksum (type = 2) 1b8cd225feb11625e1ee8bde8678c053 ((null) before)
BraseroChecksumImage Finished track successfully
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroGrowisofs getting varg
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroGrowisofs got varg:
BraseroGrowisofs deactivating
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroGrowisofs getting varg
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_speed
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_device
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroGrowisofs got varg:
    growisofs
    -use-the-force-luke=notray
    -use-the-force-luke=4gms
    -dvd-compat
    -speed=4
    -use-the-force-luke=tracksize:4155840
    -use-the-force-luke=tty
    -Z
    /dev/sr0=/[....]/Xeno.iso
BraseroGrowisofs Launching command
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroGrowisofs stdout: Executing 'builtin_dd if=/home/max4/Downloads/WII - Xenoblade Chronicles (USA)/Xeno.iso of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroGrowisofs stderr: /dev/sr0: splitting layers at 2077920 blocks
BraseroGrowisofs stderr: /dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 1.0x1352KBps.
BraseroGrowisofs stderr: :-[ WRITE@LBA=0h failed with SK=5h/CANNOT WRITE MEDIUM - INCOMPATIBLE FORMAT]: Wrong medium type
BraseroGrowisofs stderr: :-( media is not formatted or unsupported.
BraseroGrowisofs stderr: :-( write failed: Wrong medium type
BraseroGrowisofs stderr: HUP
BraseroGrowisofs stdout: HUP
BraseroGrowisofs process finished with status 124
BraseroGrowisofs called brasero_job_error
BraseroGrowisofs finished with an error
BraseroGrowisofs asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 0
    message = "no message"
BraseroGrowisofs stopping
Session error : unknown (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2859)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a strange effect here. growisofs believes after inquiring the
medium type and state that it is a double-layer medium which can be written.
But already the first WRITE command fails with a complaint by the drive
that it cannot write to medium. (That would be sense code 2 30 05)

There have been cases where growisofs habit to set the layer break
address of double-layer media caused failures. (But about as often the
habit of libburn to let the drive decide about the layer break caused
trouble, too.)

It would be interesting to see the assessment of drive and medium
by growisofs companion dvd+rw-mediainfo

```
dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0 long
```

If you want to try with a libburn based program, use Xfburn or this
command line example with xorriso:

```
xorriso -as cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject Xeno.iso
```

Have a nice day :)

Thomas